# Xerces-C++ 3.1 Dom exception while creating document

Tags: c++, exception, xerces

i just started learning to use xerces 3.1. I started creating a simple example, but i get an exception, when I create a DomDocument. Here is my code:

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE

int main(void) {
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
    DOMImplementation*    domImplementationPtr = NULL;
    domImplementationPtr = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(
         XMLString::transcode("core"));
    DOMDocument*        domDocumentPtr = NULL;
    std::string tagName = "Hello World";
    XMLCh* xmlTagName = XMLString::transcode(tagName.c_str());
    domDocumentPtr =  domImplementationPtr->createDocument(0, xmlTagName, 0);
    domDocumentPtr->release();
    XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();

return 0;}
```

When I execute the program it throws: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'xercesc_3_1::DOMException'

Comment: Can you add a try/catch block to catch the exception?

Comment: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-3.html gives the sample to insert try catch

Comment: Of course I can catch the exception, but this does not help me getting a working program, since the exception tells me that something is wrong...

Comment: Can you brief the details of caught exception?

Comment: ok guys i figured out, why there was an exception. tags can not have a space. If I write std::string tagName = "HelloWorld"; it works fine